# Navbar bootstrap 3 doesn't work in bootsrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have the same navbar in two HTML pages. On one page, it works perfectly with `bootstrap/3.3.7`. On the other page, I used Cards in Bootstrap 4. 
When I comment out `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`, Cards works fine and navbar is not working. When I comment out `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">,`
 navbar is working but the Cards are not working. 
Here is my code:
[my code](https://codepen.io/Rihanna91/pen/Vdejgj)

Comment: Bootstrap is on flex so belive me it will destroy many thinks cause I have faced both major and minor issues while updating it from 3 to 4 stable. and one thing please use 4.1.1 cause after updating from 3 to 4. if you update from 4 stable from 4.1.1 it cause some minor alignment issues

Comment: @OwaizYusufi I'm trying 4.1.1 but the result is totally different. It's not even working with the navigation bar I'm building with 4.0.0.

Comment: BS4 is a major release with breaking changes, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why would you use 2 versions of bootstrap. bootstrap 4 has its own navbar. look at docs and use only bootstrap 4 so you can have both navbar and cards